# Is it possible to run mc from within SSH terminal of Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, ssh, mc, intellij-15

I can run it, but it looks ugly:

[image]

Is it possible to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. You just need to change encoding of the SSH terminal:

[image]

I chosen UTF-8. Now it looks as expected:

[image]

Hope, it will be helpful for someone else, too.